# Allow user to flip webpage/section upside down with button?

Tags: html, rotation, css-animations, transform

I'm looking to allow visitors to my website the ability to rotate the webpage upside (180º) with the click of a button.

I know I can go into the CSS and add the following code to completely flip it:

```
body{
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

But I want to be able to give the user the ability to essentially turn this on/off. Is there a way to do this?

**BONUS POINTS** if the rotation can be CSS animated to do a smooth transition. But not required.

Comment: The way your question is phrased, it sounds like you just want somebody to do it for you. When asking a question here, you're expected to have done extensive research and attempted to solve the problem yourself. Then, if you still haven't solved it, you ask here, showing your code and asking a specific question about where you got stuck. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @Ouroborus – How is me adding an example of 180deg rotation CSS for the body not an example of any legwork I did for figuring out how to rotate my content? Then I came here to simply ask how to allow users to activate that. Careful you don't fall when getting off your high horse

Comment: It shows little to no attempt at researching the problem. There are many, many tutorials on the topics you asked about. I gave you an overview of how to do it earlier and suggested looking at tutorials. It will take effort on your part. That is expected. If/when you run into a specific problem, post a new question, following the guidelines in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you'll likely get a response more directed at the specific problem you ask about.

Comment: Note: no browser has needed those vendor prefixes in many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an event to a button or link, and on click, the page will flip.

```js
  const button = document.querySelector('.button');

  const changeClass = (e) => {
    const body = document.querySelector('.main');
    body.classList.toggle('rotate');
  };

  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    changeClass(e);
  });
```

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .main {
    background: url(https://japan-forward.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Mt-Fuji-Eruption-Volcano-006-scaled.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .text {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .button {
    width: 140px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .footer {
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="button">Click to rotate 180</button>
    <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```